# How can I create puppet eyes?

Tags: puppet

I'm doing a class on puppets and trying to find a variety of good eye balls so that my students have as many options as possible.  I've seen a few examples:

- plastic spoons
- ping pong balls
- googly eyes
- casting your own (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwopqYjSASQ)
- Half Round Wood Beads

Of the list above, casting eyes looks the best, and plastic spoons are the most versatile for different sizes and shapes.  But I know this list can't be complete.  What are some other things that can be used to create eye balls on puppets?

Comment: Found a good video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l-8maBHWdA

Comment: What sort of puppet (what material)? And what sort of size? You can buy eyes for making cuddly (plush) toys that fasten through fabric. They would work for glove puppets, for example

Comment: Safety eyes, taxidermy eyes, doll eyes... What kind of materials are you using, and what style of puppet?

Comment: My base material at the moment is fuzzy socks for a glove puppet, though I'm not going for traditional sock puppets.  That being said, my goal is to give students as many options as possible and also choose materials that might work well for other projects.  Taxidermy eyes are wild!

Comment: Hi Seph, welcome to Arts & Crafts! You're asking for a rolling list, which isn't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. Please add as many requirements as you can into your question (through an [edit]), and we'll leave it to the community to decide if it can be reopened.

Comment: As a former decades long software developer, I'm well versed in the stack-exchange format.  Looking at other questions on this site, most seem to be "rolling list" in the sense that there's an infinite amount of artistic answers.  The big difference is that most questions ask "how can I" rather than "what can I use."  As such, I've changed my question accordingly to fit the "infinite answers but not a rolling list" rule.

Comment: Changing the title and wording has not changed your question's goal... a list of ideas for you to pick from. Such a thing could be endless.

Comment: Please look at the questions that start with "How can I"  https://crafts.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+can+I.  Almost all of them have an endless amount of possible answers.  Almost all of them are a list of ideas from which the asker picks one.  In any case, they'll be a bit better off.  But nothing was gained by closing this question.

Comment: What was gained is adherence to a guide that has been established by the community. The format of this platform is simply not a good fit for this type of questions. You are welcome to start a discussion on [Meta] about this: maybe you can win everyone over. In any case, your edit hasn't changed your question (except your titular question is now different from what you're actually asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the most simple option you could draw or paint eyes on the puppet with water resistent markers or paints.

You could glue any object on the puppet that resembles eyes, like the typical googly eyes, cut-out paper, cardboard or plastic eyes, sequins or random stuff you find lying around.

With the use of a needle and thread you could sew on different eyes like beads, cabochons or big rhinestones, but you could also embroider an eye from just the thread or sew on little patches of a different fabric.

If the object you want to sew on as an eye doesn't have holes, there's also the technique of [Shisha or mirror-work embroidery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shisha_(embroidery)) with which you can attach small, flat objects to fabric without sewing through the object.

Really, the options are vast. I bet you could walk through a home construction store or empty out a trash container and find various objects you could use as eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is traditional to use buttons as the eyes of dolls or puppets in western European countries.